# Query builder with 4 tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This is my query builder function :

```
public function MonthSoldGDV($dev,$year){

            $monthlyGDV = DB::table('pams_unit')
            ->join('pams_phase','pams_unit.phase_id','pams_phase.phase_id')
            ->join('pams_project','pams_phase.project_id','pams_project.project_id')
            ->join('pams_developer','pams_project.dev_id ','pams_developer.id')
            ->select('pams_developer.developer_name')
            ->selectRaw('year(pams_unit.sold_date) as year')
            ->selectRaw('month(pams_unit.sold_date) as month')
            ->selectRaw('sum(pams_unit.sold_price) as gdv')
            ->where('pams_developer.developer_name','$dev')
            ->whereRaw('year(sold_date) = $year')
            ->groupBy('month')
            ->get();

            return $monthlyGDV;

        }
```

But it show an error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$year' in 'where clause'`

Can someone help me to figure out my problem ?

Comment: `'year(sold_date) = $year'` - That will literally translate as that. If you want to use the _value_ of `$year`, it must be inside double quotes. The same goes with `'$dev'`. That will only match developers with the literal name `$dev`. There you can remove the quotes completely though, since you send it in as a separate argument.

Comment: Also, be sure to do a `$year = (int)$year;` first (casting the value as an integer to prevent possible SQL injections).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes you may need to use a raw expression in a query. To create a raw expression, you may use the DB::raw method:

in your case, `'$year'` PHP think that `'$year'` is a `string` character, not a variable and `whereRaw`  meaning use raw expression.
This is the reason for your error

```
$monthlyGDV = DB::table('pams_unit')
    ->join('pams_phase', 'pams_unit.phase_id', '=', 'pams_phase.phase_id') //changed
    ->join('pams_project', 'pams_phase.project_id', '=', 'pams_project.project_id') //changed
    ->join('pams_developer', 'pams_project.dev_id ', '=', 'pams_developer.id') //changed
    ->select('pams_developer.developer_name')
    ->selectRaw('year(pams_unit.sold_date) as year')
    ->selectRaw('month(pams_unit.sold_date) as month')
    ->selectRaw('sum(pams_unit.sold_price) as gdv')
    ->where('pams_developer.developer_name', $dev) //changed
    ->where(DB::raw('year(sold_date)'), $year) //changed
    ->groupBy('month')
    ->get();
```

**EDIT**:

```
    public function join($table, $one, $operator = null, $two = null, $type = 'inner', $where = false)
    {
        // If the first "column" of the join is really a Closure instance the developer
        // is trying to build a join with a complex "on" clause containing more than
        // one condition, so we'll add the join and call a Closure with the query.
        if ($one instanceof Closure) {
            $join = new JoinClause($type, $table);
```

notice that the third parameter is `$operator`, so you should do something like this

```
join('pams_developer', 'pams_project.dev_id ', '=', 'pams_developer.id')
```

Comment: You should include a proper explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but now it show `Unknown column 'pams_project.dev_id ' in 'on clause'`  . But i am sure there is a `dev_id` structure in my `pams_project` table.

Comment: @HoWeiKang ok, I  updated the an answer

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Just because I am not good at English :(

Comment: Nah, your English seems fine! :-)

Comment: @HoWeiKang - If the database says it can't find that column in that table, it most likely don't exist.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You are encouraging me? I am very worried about whether others can understand me .

Comment: I understand you fine so I'm sure others will to. Also, practice makes perfect!

Comment: @qskane, thanks for your response but sadly the error output is same..